# Adding in Object of elements

Tags: java, database, object, arraylist, operators

There is a code on `java`

```
Object[] param = {1,2,3,4};
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", param);
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call net_trains(?, ?) }");

proc.setArray(1, array);
proc.setInt(2, Ids.get(k))
proc.execute();
```

Instead of direct initialization of an array of Object it would be desirable to have opportunity to fill it with any quantity of elements from

```
ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fill Array with elements from ArrayList.

```
for(int i =0 ; i < ProcessedTherms.size() ; i++){
    param[i] = ProcessedTherms.get(i);    
}
```

**Note:** size of ArrayList and Array should be same. Otherwise you may get IndexOutOfBound Exception.